# Error when building dlib c++ example scripts in eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse, dlib

I received errors when build dlib c++ example script in eclipse cdt.

I have added dlib directory into the #include search oath and dlib/all/source.cpp into the project. See picture 1.

[image]

The error message I received is like picture 2:

[image]

I would like to know where is the problem and how to solve this.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to link the pthread and X window libraries. Go to linker settings and add pthread and XLib.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The script was built correctly after linking pthread and X11 library.